# The data points on the edge of the ‘band’, around the separator that makes all the data points outside the band redundant, are called what?

Tags: svm

The data points on the edge of the ‘band’, around the separator that makes all the data points outside the band redundant, are called what? Please find the options

1. Support vectors
2. Support vector machines
3. Maximum margins
4. Support Vector Classifiers

Answer (score 0):

Support vectors are the data points that lie close to the Support Vector Classifier; they are the only data points used for constructing the classifier.